# Prove that $ \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n $

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Original question: Let a sample space $S$ have $n$ elements. Prove
>   that the number of subsets of $ S $ is $2^n$.

*Key insight*: The amount of subsets of a set can be counted using combinations. For example, if a set has $ 2 $ elements, then the number of subsets is:

$$ \binom{2}{0} + \binom{2}{1} + \binom{2}{2} = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4 $$

Therefore, if a set $ S $ has $ n $ elements, then $ S $ has

$$ \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + ... + \binom{n}{n} $$ subsets

Thus, proving that a set with $ n $ elements has $ 2^n $ subsets amounts to proving the following statement:

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n $$

The most obvious way to prove this equality seems to be by induction. A set with $ n = 1 $ elements has $ \binom{1}{0} + \binom{1}{1} = 2 $ subsets, so the base case holds. Now we assume the equality works for $ n $ and show that it works for $ n+1 $:

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i} = 2^{n+1} $$

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n+2}{i} = 2 \times 2^n $$
This is where I'm stumbling.

Comment: Binomial theorem applied to $(1+1)^n$?

Comment: @lulu Sorry, your comment came when I was typing the answer.

Comment: I counted 5 duplicates of this question on math.se.

Comment: @Vladimir  No need for apologies!  Even if you had seen my comment before posting your solution, anything written in a comment is fair game for anyone to use.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up a duplicate of this question. I did search for a proof here before posting the question, just didn't find any.

Comment: Solving the original question by using the binomial theorem is absurdly overcomplicated. Each element can be in or out, so $2^n$ possible subsets.

Comment: @almagest Sad but true...

Answer (score 3):

To prove that, notice that the equality you wish to prove is just Newton's binomial formula for $(1+1)^n$.